# Is there some alternative to disabling the logic that converts base64 images into blobs?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

The 'images_dataimg_filter' option can also be used to specify a filter predicate function for disabling the logic that converts base64 images into blobs while within the editor.

[image]

With the new version of TinyMCE 6.1.0 the option images_dataimg_filter was removed. Is there some alternative to disabling the logic that converts base64 images into blobs.

Please share if any way to solve this.

Thanks